# PHP: Push Elements of Arrays into new Arrays for each Element

Tags: php, arrays, split, push

I have 2 Arrays and want to push each first element to one array, each second to the next one and so on:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e [5] => f)
Array ( [0] => g [1] => h [2] => i [3] => j [4] => k [5] => l)
```

convert into:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => g) 
Array ( [0] => b [1] => h) 
Array ( [0] => c [1] => i) 
Array ( [0] => d [1] => j) 
Array ( [0] => e [1] => k) 
Array ( [0] => f [1] => l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Your two arrays
$arrays = array(
    array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
    array('g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l')
);

// Fill new arrays
$res = array();
foreach($arrays as $array) {
    foreach($array as $i => $item) {
        $res[$i][] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($res);
/*
 Array ( [0] => a [1] => g) 
 Array ( [0] => b [1] => h) 
 Array ( [0] => c [1] => i) 
 Array ( [0] => d [1] => j) 
 Array ( [0] => e [1] => k) 
 Array ( [0] => f [1] => l)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I need! The arrays are rows of a database and I save each them into a new array and push them to the array '$arrays':



    `$rows = mysql_num_rows($db_select);
    $arrays = array();
    
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
      ${"e".$i} = mysql_fetch_array( $db_select, MYSQL_ASSOC);
      array_push($arrays, ${"e".$i});
    }`

Answer (score 2):

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array1 as $i => $elem) {
    $results[$i] = array($elem, $array2[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a pointer: Assuming that both arrays have the same length. The new array will be stored in `newArray` Iterate with a counter variable `i` to the length of `array1`, for each loop, create a new array in `newArray` with the elements at index `i` from `array1` and `array2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$one = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$two = ['g','h','i','j','k','l'];

$merged_arrays = array_map( function( $item, $key ) use ( $two )
{
    return [$item, $two[$key]];

}, $one, array_keys( $one ) );
```